# XAMPP installation issue on mac // bitnami-first-boot-123456

Tags: php, sql, installation, xampp

I was following this tutorial https://youtu.be/EK_AUTzV7OI on how to. install XAMPP on mac but when he tell to open terminal at 4:37 then he give command ls in starting which opens list of options but. i'm getting the following
[image]

I don't know what to do about (bitnami-first-boot-123456)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in the home directory (illustrated by the ~ sign), they are in the root.
Try

```
cd /
ls
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing the directory to / using `cd /` works. Then you can work your way through using ls commands.